# What's a good way to change something on a web page based on scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I want to do is to change css of some elements, based on scrolling. For example I have a div and want to make it's opacity at 0 when a website is scrolled down by 500px, but I want to make it with transition, e.g when the website is scrolled down by 250px, opacity should be 0.5 I am looking for a good way, having several if statements in a scroll loop is not so good, maybe there are some libraries to do this?

Comment: To detect scrolling use the `scroll` event as raised by the document. To do the transition, use CSS.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that I want opacity to be at 0 only when the website is scrolled down completely, if it is just in the midway that div should stay at 0.5 opacity

Comment: Do you want the opacity to change for all the continuous values or just for the special cases, of 0, 250px and 500px?

Comment: In which case you would have to do it solely in Javascript, setting the opacity value as a percentage of the scroll top position to full document height.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tew9zxc1/) will give you an idea.

Comment: Yes it should change continuously, hmm well, with percentage it should work, but I'm not sure if this is effective, I mean it's a loop with a lot of calculations.

Comment: Your opacity would be proportional to 1 - (scrollTop / scrollTopMax)

Comment: @AMD_Paulius it's not a loop at all. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: Since you want want opacity to be zero at the end it has to be a bit backwards. But it's pretty easy; opacity = 1 - (currentScrollPos / endScrollPos). So at 400 px scroll we get; 1 - 400 / 500 = 0.2. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want the gradient setting to be related to the scroll position of the page you would need to do this solely in Javascript. You can work out the entire scrollable length of the page by subtracting the `window.height` from the `document.height`. From there you can calculate the percentage opacity from the `document.scrollTop`. Try this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollableHeight = $(this).height() - $(window).height();
    var opacity = 1 - ($(document).scrollTop() / scrollableHeight);
    $('header').css('opacity', opacity);
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xy0knybc/)

Comment: Beware that (afaik) no solution will give a decent imitation of this effect on iphone and probably most other touch devices (the opacity will change suddenly when scrolling ends rather than gradually during scroll)... No events occur during scroll. So make sure to detect and disable or come up with a different approach if those devices need to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. What you should do is bind a scroll event to your window, and calculate the no. of scrolled pixels. Then you can calculate the  `opacity` according to this value like this, (here 500 is your `500px` limit)

```
opacity = (1 - scrolledNoOfPixels / 500)
```

Then change the css property of the relevant element.

```js
var scrolledValue = 0;

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scrolled = $(document).scrollTop() - scrolledValue;
    console.log("Scrolled pixels :  " + scrolled);
    $("#mydiv").css('opacity', 1 - scrolled / 500);
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 1200px;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

#mydiv{
    width:300px;
    height:1000px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

This would be pretty easy to do with some standard JavaScript, or perhaps jQuery, and math :-)

Example using background color instead of opacity:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var max = 500;
        var current = $(window).scrollTop();
        var opacity = 1 - (current / max);

        $('#box').css('background-color', 'rgba(127, 208, 249, '+opacity+')');

    });
});
```

You could just change background-color for opacity. If you really want that. But this gives you the effect I guess you are looking for.

Check full example: http://jsfiddle.net/L23gfL80/1/

Using just opacity, the content inside the box would fade away as well.

Check opacity example: http://jsfiddle.net/w2d8dura/

Comment: Why the down vote? :-S This is a perfectly working correct answer.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, it really is a working answer, so I'll upvote to make it even;]

Answer (score -3):

Checkout some CSS Parallax Scrolling Effects, that's what you're looking for, here's some useful sites:

http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

http://davidwalsh.name/parallax

You may as well do some research about it on Google, even on Youtube there're some nice tutorials.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with parallax, so I'm unsure why you're suggesting these links?

Comment: Parallax is definitely what you want.

Answer (score -3):

From the plugin site:

> Waypoints is the easiest way to trigger a function when you scroll to
>   an element.

[here is a link](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/) to the jquery plugin.

An example of an element at 20px to the top

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('px-offset-waypoint'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    notify('I am 20px from the top of the window')
  },
  offset: 20 
})
```

Comment: Sorry, sometimes being new here is a bit rough... Users here try to help make the most relevant answers rise, and get rid of those that will likely not be helpful to others doing similar research. Your solution may work, but at a glance you are answering a slightly different question (OP explicitly stated that "having several if statements [...] not good", which I think this solution involves). It also has a much larger overhead than needed for this simple effect (though the OP did ask for "libraries"). Anyway that is why I downvoted.

Comment: Because it do not really solve the problem at hand. Waypoints are good at detecting elements and trigger a function. But do not help with a smooth transition.